# Choice of \mul or \times

Tags: symbols, amsmath, packages, amssymb

Using this simple code,

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{mismath}
\begin{document}
$a\mul b, \quad a\times b$
\end{document}
```

[image]

the package `mismath` use also the symbol `\mul`. You can see that the symbol is identical but the distance between `a` and `b` is different. When should we use `\mul` and when `\times`?

Comment: `\mul` is defined as `\mathord{\times}`, so it gets an `ord`inary spacing, while `\times` is `\mathbin` (`bin`ary spacing). Unless you only want the symbol, with no spacing, I think `\times` is the correct choice...

Comment: The answer is easy: never use `\mul`, because the spacing is definitely wrong in any case. It makes no sense to use the cross symbol as an ordinary to denote a binary operation. By the way, `\times` is never used in mathematics to denote numeric multiplication (except in a few well delimited cases) beyond elementary school.

Comment: @egreg Then, what is the reason of the existence of `\mul` into the package `mismath` if "the spacing is definitely wrong in any case"?

Comment: Ask the author of the package. He provides an explanation, but I find it wrong.

Comment: Personally, I use the equivalent of `\mul` to denote the size of a matrix of determinant, in the form: `an $m{\times}n$ matrix`.

Comment: @Bernard Never in my life.

Comment: In my opinion, the spacing of `$m\times n$` is too large, and it's not a real multiplication.

Comment: Peraphs `\mul` is more adapted for a elementary product and `\times` for a vectioral product?

Comment: @Sebastiano You seem to believe that if something is in a package it is good. This is very far from truth.

Comment: @egreg I want to learn what is right and to distinguish between what is not good and what is good.

Comment: @egreg thanks for your explanations. What are those "few well delimited cases"? (I am with you btw).

Comment: You'd normally write their product as `$ab$ or $a \cdot b$.

Comment: Vector cross products use `\times`. (But vectors would be boldface letters or `$\vec{a}$` to put a little arrow above.) I’ve never seen the equivalent of `\mul` in a math or engineering paper, but I suppose someone might use closer spacing to visually emphasize the order of operations? The programming language Fortress did something like that, where you were allowed to write `a*b + c`, but `a * b+c` was a syntax error.

Comment: @Davislor Hi, for young students up to 12 years old the classic product is used x. From 12 and up you use in Algebra Elementary the product \cdot and then this is omitted. For the vector product I use the common notation \times. The notation of vector product \wedge is used by some Italian authors but I don't like it.